# Translation of fields

Tags: i18n-l10n

By mistake I deleted a translation item instead o editing it in admin/config/regional/translate/translate, and now it seems to be gone. Is there any way to get it back to the list of translatable fields?

Cheers
/bo

Answer (score 1):

View the page this item is supposed to appear on, Drupal will encounter the item and add it to the translation interface again.

Comment: I have tried to visit the page both as logged in user and not logged in but it does not seem to have been added to the translation interface. I have also tried to flush the cache but no success. Any way to add it more "explicity"? Am I correct to assume that the data is in the database as a textblob?

Comment: That's the explicit way. Only other way I can think of is disabling, uninstalling and reinstalling the module which defines this translation item. Shot into the blue would be the Localization Update module (https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) if the original module already has translation set files.